# validation onsubmit for a class

Tags: javascript, validation

I have some fields and for the fields that I want to validate I hava a class associated with it. Now while submiting the form I need to validate the fields. Can anyone show me the syntax how to do it.
for example:

```
<form action="form_action.asp" method="get" onSubmit= "return validateFields()">
  First name: <input type="text" class="abc" name="fname" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" class="abc" name="lname" /><br />
 age: <input type="text" class="zzz" name="age" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: You have to show the conditions that validate them. When are they supposed to be invalid?

Comment: @divya which programming language ?? please add more info how would you like to validate just empty fields or based on regular expression ?

Comment: validate is field numeric. I am using isNaN for onChange. But now I have to use onSubmit to validate the fields

Comment: Can you tell us what languages you are using? Is it safe to assume that you are using html and when you say classes associated you mean assigned to the element? for example <div class="myClass">

Comment: have you tried anything using javascript ?? if you did post it!!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want client-side validation, you can use the [Jquery Validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) plugin:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        fname: { required: true },
        lname: { required: true },
        age: { required: true }
    }
});
```

Or, put it directly in the HTML markup:

```
<form action="form_action.asp" method="get" onSubmit= "return validateFields()">
    First name: <input type="text" class="abc required" name="fname" /><br />
    Last name: <input type="text" class="abc required" name="lname" /><br />
    age: <input type="text" class="zzz required" name="age" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I am creating all the fields on the fly. So I don't have the name for the field. So what I am trying to do is, associate a class for all the same type of fields and do validation

Comment: @divya Take a look at the docs for the jquery validate plugin.  You can also add `class="required"` in the HTML for each item

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to use id's

```
First name: <input type="text" class="abc" name="fname" id="fnameElem" /><br />
```

Then you can validate if it is empty with

```
    if (document.getElementById('fnameElem').value == ''){
        alert('First name cannot be blank');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: How about this: not sure if it works: numeric is the class name       $("#aForm").submit(function() {
  var val = $('.numeric').val();
  if(isNaN(val)){
   alert("Not a Number");
   return false;
  }
    return true;
  });